# Geochemical maps with QGIS: Case of multiple analyses in a point

Tags: qgis, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I am a newbie, using QGIS 3.4. My goal is to create geochemical maps of species distribution in water samples. I mine data from a database, regarding specific points, which are boreholes or springs. Those points are sampled periodically. I turn them to a csv file and finally I get a point layer with multiple analyses corresponding to each point.

I try to create water species distribution maps for an area using Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW), but I get bad results. Can I know which of the analyses the software uses to produce results? Is there a way to choose the most reliable (in my opinion) analysis? Or would you rather propose a statistical processing instead, before interpolating?

Comment: If you want to know how QGIS performs a specific analysis, have a look at the [QGIS User Guide](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/) and additional documentation. If you use one of the tools from an outside toolset (eg the SAGA, GRASS and GDAL tools), refer to the manual for that toolset. Each tool in the toolbox is nested under a section header that tells you which set it comes from.